# Where it is safe to store files?

Tags: android, path, location

I am writing a Android app and I need to store some information on the device, but I don't want that this information is wiped out, when the user presses "Clean Data" on the Application Manager. I also don't want to store in the "normal" locations, where images and music are stored, because the user could see it and delete it.

Where it is the best location to store such files?

Comment: If it's data that the user really shouldn't have access to - his device is not the place to store it.

Comment: But it is a Unique ID. I need to store on the users device.

Comment: How and when did you generate this Unique ID?

Comment: I generate this id on the first start of the app. The ID consists on a very long number.

Comment: What is the minimum  API of your app?

Comment: Various API's. I can't use the device ID. Some chinese phones and tablets have as ID "123456789ABCDEF"...

Comment: Even if you're using android.os.Build.SERIAL? (API >=9)

Comment: Yes. Some chinese phone have the same ID's...

Comment: I really don't think you'll find 100% method, your assumption should be that if the user wants to delete this data - he will. You should think of a way to get the best results, and take into consideration it won't be 100%.

Comment: The problem is that this ID is essential, because I'm using a database who the user can vote in the app and then the ID went registered in the DB to prevent that the user could vote twice or trice... But if the user deletes this file, the app creates a new ID and the user can vote again :/

Comment: If someone wants to cheat, what prevents him from accessing your web service and fake unlimited ids?

Comment: Yeah, that's also a problem, but I want to make it "more" difficult...

Answer (score 0):

I would encrypt by javax.crypto.* package.

JCA Reference Guide here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html

example: https://code.google.com/p/secrets-for-android/source/browse/trunk/src/net/tawacentral/roger/secrets/SecurityUtils.java

To store you can use simple SharedPreferences

Comment: If the user clears the data of your app, SharedPreferences is gone :)

Comment: It's not the problem on encrypting. It is a problem of the user deleting the file.

Comment: hm so if I understand you right, you want to create a permanent file the smartphone owner cant delete :D?

Comment: Of course the user can delete it, if they really want to, but I want to make it more difficult.

Comment: jsut put the content in a normal file, create a local folder with your apps name and store it. User will need a file browser to delte it and most common app user wont have a clue. Or rethink your id creation ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think your assumption should be the you can't prevent it without some sort of login.
You can't really prevent anonymous users from cheating and you should consider how important this data is, and how much you are willing to invest in order to get the best result.

That said, in order to make it more difficult to cheat, I would use **android.os.Build.SERIAL**
and even though it's not 100% unique, it's still better than nothing.

In order to make it harder to generate serials, I would also encrypt this serial, so if some user sniffs your requests and wants to vote more than once he would also need to know how to encrypt it.

Again if some user wants to cheat he can, but in this way you at least eliminate the lazy cheaters :)